# g++ giving error error: 'gets' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I am having a sample `CPP` program which I am trying to compile using `g++`. But after running the command

```
g++ -o test.out test.cpp
```

I am getting error

```
test.cpp:7:6: error: 'gets' is not a member of 'std'
 std::gets(ch);
      ^~~~
test.cpp:7:6: note: suggested alternative: 'less'
 std::gets(ch);
      ^~~~
      less
```

When I check the version of `g++` using `g++ --version`, I am getting the below output

> g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
> Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

**Below is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch[100];
    std::gets(ch);
    puts(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody please try to help me how to fix this? As of now, it is not possible to change the versions. I need to make it run in this same version if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::gets` has been deprecated(in c++11) and removed(in c++14).

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: Even before `std::gets()` was removed, the code was still wrong, as `<stdio.h>` needed to be `<cstdio>` to get the `std` version of `gets()`. Otherwise, you could have dropped the `std::` qualifier to use the global C version from `<stdio.h>`, like you did with `puts()`

Answer (score 0):

`std::gets` has been deprecated(in c++11) and removed(in c++14). Thus it won't work with modern c++.

From [std::gets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets):

> ```
> char* gets( char* str );
>       (deprecated in C++11)
>       (removed in C++14)
> ```
>
> The std::gets() function does not perform bounds checking. Therefore, this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on stdin). For this reason, **the function was deprecated in C++11 and removed altogether in C++14. `std::fgets()` may be used instead.**